# Unable to fetch multi selected values in paper listbox polymer3

Tags: javascript, npm, polymer

I am trying get multiselected values in paper-list box polymer

```
 <paper-dropdown-menu label="{{_getLabel('Activity Type')}}" id="fromMenu" on-paper-dropdown-close="fromAccountChanged" searchable="true"> 
          <paper-listbox selected="{{value}}"  id="ddtype" on-iron-select="SelectedType"  attr-for-selected="value" selected="{{typeList}}" class="dropdown-content" slot="dropdown-content" multi>
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{typeList}}">
              <paper-item value="{{item}}">{{item}}</paper-item>
            </template>
          </paper-listbox>
        </paper-dropdown-menu>



SelectedType(e){
var selectedItem = e.target.selectedItem;
console.log(selectedItem.value)
var product_value = selectedItem.value;
this.searchTypeString = selectedItem.value;
```

}

This is function that i am using to fetching values but only getting single value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `selectedItems` property to get the selected `paper-item` elements, or the `selectedValues` property to get the values of the selected `paper-items`. See the [documentation](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/@polymer/paper-listbox/elements/paper-listbox#properties) for further information.